# An excel formula to find a row/column index in array

Tags: excel-formula

I have an excel table array, with row and columns indexes.
Inside the array, there are some empyu cells and some cells with unique values.

Now i want to get a simplified table, when in first column i have the list of the unique values from the table array and in second column, to get the exact cells of this value as a function of concatenation between row and column index.
First this is the table example:

```
    a   b   c   d
31              RESET_N
30  A[9]        A[11]   
29      A[6]        A[7]
28  A[3]        A[4]
```

And desired table:

```
A[9] a30
A[3] a28
```

etc

thanks

Answer (score 0):

`=B2&A2` should be sufficient, but you would have to 'reverse pivot' first and maybe delete blanks en route. In Excel 2007:

Add label in A1.
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+D, P.

[image: SO19092681 example]

Drill down on `7` (the intersect of the `Grand Total`s).
For `Value` filter for `(Blanks)` only and delete selected rows. 
Take off filter and add formula in D2. 
Sort and delete surplus, if desired.