# Is there an easy way to reformat a poorly-formatted tree to a two-column table?

Tags: excel, database-design, data-structures, vba

I have a table representing a series of components and their subcomponents, and the subcomponents' respective subcomponents, and so on. It currently looks like a tree (one-to-many relations), but it could change at some point to resemble a graph (many-to-many relations) instead. Unfortunately, it was poorly formatted by its author, and looks something like this:

[image: Poorly-formatted table]

The above format is poor because there is a lot of data duplication and it is limited to a set number (4) of tiers. I would instead prefer if it looked something like this:

[image: Nicely-formatted table]

The above format is nice because there is very little data duplication, and it is not limited to a set number of tiers.

In case there is any confusion about what the tables represent, here is a graphical representation of the data:

[image: graphical tree]

It is simple enough to convert from the poor format to the nice format, but there are hundreds of root components, and manual data entry would be far too time-consuming and tedious.

I suspect this problem is unique and I am prepared to write some VBA code myself to parse the table into the nice format, but I thought I'd make sure that this wasn't a common problem with a pre-rolled solution before I rolled my own.

Is there a technical term to describe the poor formatting in the first table? Is there an easier way to reformat the data than to write a VBA macro?

Comment: What is the relationship between Tier & (sub)component fields?  what is the anchor field for your values?

Comment: `2` is a child of `1` with no children of its own, as is `3`. `4` is also a child of `1`, and it has two children, `5` and `6`. I have edited the question to contain a visual representation of the data.

Comment: There is something missing; in the first data set you have 3 unique entries for 4-1, in rows 4, 5 & 6.  In the second data set you only an entry in row 4 for these three.  As is all you have to do is some copy and paste of columns and remove duplicates to get the scenario you are describing.

Comment: The advantage of what you are calling "poor" formatting is that it is readily readable and understandable by human beings, whereas the more compact format you are favoring is not.  In spreadsheets like Excel, data duplication is not usually a concern, but human readability *is* so the first format is preferred (though top-to-bottom is usually left-to-right, reversed from this example).  On the other hand, in databases, data redundancy *is* a concern, but human readability of the data is *not*, so the second ("relational hierarchy") is preferred.

Comment: @JamesJenkins I know the data is formatted poorly. The fact that that row even exists only further contributes to the unsuitability of the format. However, I don't see how it's as simple as some copy and paste of columns to get it to the nicer format. There are hundreds of rows and I'm not prepared to manually copy and paste hundreds of items.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I understand the advantages and disadvantes of the views. My task is to construct a database in a RDBMS and then create proper views, using data that is (unfortunately) currently stored in a rather inefficiently-formatted Excel worksheet. For my purposes, I would definitely prefer the second format.

Comment: @JamesJenkins - I had a moment of clarity and realized what you meant by being able to copy/paste and remove duplicates. I'm going to write a detailed answer describing the process.

Comment: What's with the downvotes? Would it have been better suited for SuperUser, or do users feel that it's just a silly question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied each pair of adjacent columns in the `Tier` table (`Tier 1` & `Tier 2`, `Tier 2` & `Tier 3`, `Tier 3` & `Tier 4`) and pasted them stacked vertically into a single pair of columns (`Subcomponent` & `Component`).

Next, I removed duplicates by selecting both of my new columns and clicking `Remove Duplicates` in the `Data` ribbon tab.

Next, I had to remove all rows which contained a blank cell in the `Subcomponent` column. To do this, I selected both columns again and filtered the data by clicking `Filter` in the `Data` ribbon tab. I selected `(Blanks)` in the `Filter` menu on the `Subcomponent` column and deleted all visible rows. I removed the filer by selecting `(Select All)` in the filter menu.

The resulting table contained many blank rows, so again I removed duplicates, and then manually shifted the data up one row to displace the one remaining blank row.

In the end, it took about a half hour, which is probably less time than it would have taken me to code a macro, and definitely less time than manual data entry.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a complete aberration but it works for your sample (and at the moment I don’t have time to break it!)

Add an index (and a label for it) and `reverse pivot` (eg see [An excel formula to find a row/column index in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092681/an-excel-formula-to-find-a-row-column-index-in-array/19115042#19115042)).
Instead of drilling down on the `Grand Total`s intercept, drill down on each of the totals for the Tiers.

Reassemble the tables side by side, delete all columns except the `Value` ones and copy table to another area with Paste Special Values. Remove Duplicates on the range. Every time the value in the column immediately to the right does not change, delete and shift the values in the cells to the left. Reorder the columns right to left.

Comment: I appreciate the input, and reading this helped me realize what @JamesJenkins was getting at with his comment. However, the solution I came up with uses a slightly different method, which I think is more elgant since it doesn't involve reverse pivot or an index. I'd appreciate your feedback on it, if you could take a look at it.

Comment: "Small" is relative but the dataset I was looking at has about 300 records. Also, the half hour mostly consisted of thinking and Googling basic Excel features, which I would've had to do regardless of which method I chose. If I had to repeat the task, I'm confident I could complete it in < 5 minutes.