# Summarise data based on date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have a set of data in excel that looks like this:

```
Project Name alpha date alpha price beta date beta price final date final price
Project a 1/01/2013 $123.00 2/02/2013 $324.00 5/02/2013 $222.00
Project b 2/01/2013 $432.00 9/03/2013 $111.00 30/03/2013 $321.00
project c 2/02/2013 $4,431.00 8/03/2013 $231.00 7/04/2013 $343.00
project d 3/04/2013 $1,232.00 30/01/1906 $3,122.00 6/07/2013 $666.00
```

I need to generate a sum for each month/year across all projects and phases of the project. IE:

```
Jan 2013 $555
Feb 2013 $4,977
```

What's the best way of going about this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case for pivot tables.

1. Highlight the date columns, right click, Format Cells.. menu item.  Then use a Custom Data format of MM/YY to get everything in month and year format.
2. Once all the dates are converted, highlight the entire table then make a Pivot Table of the data (use Create Menu).  Place pivot table on new sheet.
3. Use the pivot table to group and sum data as needed.  You can drag the various projects into pivot table rows, and then combine cost columns using the sum() function.  Add filters or project groups where needed.

If you've never used pivot tables, I highly recommend taking 30 minutes to learn.  They are very intuitive and powerful.

Good luck!

Comment: But can you have multiple dates within the pivot?  I can't seem to get alpha data and beta data (with their relevant prices) in the same pivot.

Comment: Without transforming your original spreadsheet it's probably easiest to use two pivots.  One for Alpha and one for Beta.  Then make a third table to combine.  If data transformation is an option, stack them all in four columns: project_name, milestone_type, milestone_date, price.  Milestone type will be alpha, beta, or final.  Then pivot on this..

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion is to ‘reverse pivot’ (eg as described [An excel formula to find a row/column index in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092681/an-excel-formula-to-find-a-row-column-index-in-array)) and double click on the intersect of the `Grand Total`s.  Insert a column with:

`=MONTH(Table1[[#This Row],[Value]])&" | "&YEAR(Table1[[#This Row],[Value]])`

and a column with, in the first row below the headers (assumed to be Row1): `=C3` where C is assumed to be the Value column.
Copy the Table and Paste Special Values.
Filter the Column column and delete all rows containing `price`.
Sort the month/year column and Subtotal, for each change in that column, the other added column.