# Create new row for every single value in column

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have the following problem: I have an excel spreadsheet in which there are ids (websites) in one column and the languages in another, e.g.

ID           | Languages

20              English, Italian, German

21              Russian
22              Spanish, Czech

Now I need to create a new row for every language that a certain ID has and match these languages to a language code, so that I can import the result into a database:

ID | Language Code

20     EN

20     IT

20     DE

21     RU

22     ES

22     CZ

I got another table with the matching language/language code data, too.

How can i transform my spreadsheet into that format? I don't want to type in the languages for 1000+ websites by hand...

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You'll have to do it in 2 steps. First create the new row, then just manually replaces the languages with the language codes (replace by).

Comment: The thing is that I have approx. 1000 ids, which means that I have at more than 2000 rows in the end, as most of the ids have 2+ languages (websites)

Answer (score 0):

Parse out the multiple languages with Text to Columns then 'reverse pivot' (eg as shown here [An excel formula to find a row/column index in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092681/an-excel-formula-to-find-a-row-column-index-in-array)), double click on the intercept of the `Grand Total`s, select and delete blank values and apply codes to suit (maybe with VLOOKUP).