# PivotTable from data column pairs

Tags: excel, excel-2007, pivot-table, unpivot

I am not very familiar with pivot tables, but I can do very basic ones. However, I am trying to resolve a data set that has column pairs of data and I need to pivot the data in those pairs.

Here is a cut down version of one of the datasets (I've got about 50 to do!!).

[image: Source data]

I am trying to get this result:

[image]

I've looked at numerous videos on YouTube and searched, but not found anything to help me with this. Any pointers anyone?

Comment: It's not possible to go straight from your data to a pivot table. Probably easier to write some VBA that loops through your datasets and compiles your reformatted tables.

Comment: in addition to what @AndiMohr suggested, your search will be faster if you look for **UNPIVOT** - the data as supplied appears to have already run through a pivot (it can also be called a xross-tab or xtab)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but @pnuts answer does the job for me. There is no consistency in the number of types or contexts. The data is 99% of the time entered by hand on printed tables during (archaeological) finds processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unmerge or uncentre Types and prefix those in `No` column with `#`. Delete Context row. ‘Reverse pivot’ (eg [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092681/an-excel-formula-to-find-a-row-column-index-in-array)) and double click on `Grand Total`s intersection. Filter for `(Blanks)` in Value column and delete those rows. Sort A to Z Column column and move lower set up and to the right of upper set. Delete `Column1` and sort Row Smallest to Largest. Move THT above second SHC, if required. Add labels to suit.

I suggest you get this to work for one dataset then see if possible to apply process the one time to all 50.

Comment: Great, inevitably a bit long winded, but that did the job. Unfortunately none of the 50 odd datasets will be consistent in the number of types or contexts, so it won't work as a batch or an easy to write VBA. This will work for what I need.

Comment: Much appreciated. There was a tiny bit of manipulation and fiddling, but your explanation and the example you linked me to was enough.